# How to change size of header in wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, header

I made a website in wordpress. When i upload a logo for my site identity the size of the Header menu gets bigger. I changed the size of the logo already but the Header size (in height) still gets bigger.

Does anyone know maybe?

I have changed the size of the logo

Comment: Set max-width for image using css something like img.logo {max-width: 100px;}

Comment: Hi @Beneris, It doesn'tt work